# Why do my left/right outer join return data from the opposite side table?

Tags: sql-server

So i have 4 tables and I am trying to join them based on various tags and ids. As we can examine below,
i have  my top CTE that grabs all the data that is greater than zero from table Datalog.

My second CTE grabs all the data from Datalog that is either equal to zero or equal to null.

However, doing some inner joins and right outer join with each of the cte then doing a union of
the CTE to grab the end results that includes all the tags from the GblTagStructure with data corresponding 
to the structure.

One of the requirement was that my end result cannot have any of the tags with data=0. If any of them 
equal to zero then I should replace that zero with the latest value that is logged in the datalog.

This is what my Final cte does and after that I just do a select to grab all the data in the format I want.

The problem is, not all my tags from GblTagStructure are are included in my end result. I have been told that 
this cannot happen since all the tags are collecting data on a regular basis. So where is my mistake? 
Are my joins wrong?
What the result indicates is that when i use right outer join i get all the tags that are in gbltagstructure which is on the left side, and when i use left outer join i a bunch of unwanted tags from the right side... I may not understand joins correctly also.

So please help me learn when to use left/right outer join.

I have included some images of my tables, the reason for not having a sqlfiddle is that there is simply too much data 
in my tables to replicate it.So I am hopping we can tackle this without a sqlfiddle.

```
declare @DateTime as Datetime
set @DateTime = '2015-12-01'

;with Data as ( select distinct a.timestamputc as times, c.name, cast(a.Data as float) as data, d.tag,a.MeterTagId, b.name as Type from DataLog a
                        inner join MeterTags b on b.metertagid = a.MeterTagId
                        inner join Meters c on c.MeterId = b.meterid
                        right outer join GblTagStructure d on d.metertagid = a.metertagid
                        --where TimestampUTC<=dateadd(day,1,dateadd(mi,-1,@DateTime)) and TimestampUTC>=dateadd(day,0,@DateTime)  and a.Data>0),
                        --where a.TimestampUTC = dateadd(d,-0,convert(date,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,110)) and a.Data > 0),
                        where a.TimestampUTC = dateadd(d,0,'2015-12-17') and a.Data > 0 )
lesszero as (select distinct a.timestamputc as times, c.name, cast(a.Data as float) as data, d.tag, a.MeterTagId, b.name as Type from DataLog a
                        inner join MeterTags b on b.metertagid = a.MeterTagId
                        inner join Meters c on c.MeterId = b.meterid
                        right outer join gbltagstructure d on d.metertagid = a.metertagid
                        --where TimestampUTC<=dateadd(day,1,dateadd(mi,-1,@DateTime)) and TimestampUTC>=dateadd(day,0,@DateTime)   and a.Data=0 ),
                        --where a.TimestampUTC >= dateadd(d,0,convert(date,2015-12-17,110)) and a.Data = 0 )
                        where a.TimestampUTC = dateadd(d,0,'2015-12-12') and a.Data = 0 or a.data is null )
Final as(select distinct cast(times as Date) as DateTime, Name,Data,Tag from Data a 
union all 
select distinct cast(b.times as Date) as DateTime,b.name as Name,Data=(select max(data) from DataLog where timestamputc >= (select MAX(timestamputc) from DataLog where MeterTagId=b.metertagid 
and data>0) 
and MeterTagId=b.metertagid and data>0 ) , Tag
from lesszero b )

Select distinct DateTime, Name as ParameterName, Max(Data) as DataValue, Tag from Final
Group By Name, Tag, DateTime
```

[GBLTagStructure Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auEkj.png)

[MeterTags Table][2]

[Meters Table][3]

[DataLog table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HupWA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the JOINs is correct.  The problem is your `WHERE` clause.

You basically do this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableA
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB ON ...
WHERE TableA.SomeColumn = 'Something'
```

So you start off getting all rows in `TableB`, and if there is no match in `TableA`, you get NULL in the `TableA` columns.

Then your WHERE clause eliminates all the rows where the `TableA` columns are NULL.

If you move the WHERE clause conditions involving `TableA` to the ON clause of the JOIN instead, then you will get all rows from `TableB` as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Move the the `left` table filters to `ON` condition when you are using `Right Outer Join` else only the matched results will get filtered end result will be same as `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.timestamputc        AS times, 
                c.NAME, 
                Cast(a.data AS FLOAT) AS data, 
                d.tag, 
                a.metertagid, 
                b.NAME                AS type 
FROM   datalog a 
       INNER JOIN metertags b 
               ON b.metertagid = a.metertagid 
                  AND a.timestamputc = Dateadd(d, 0, '2015-12-17') 
                  AND a.data > 0 
       INNER JOIN meters c 
               ON c.meterid = b.meterid 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN gbltagstructure d 
                     ON d.metertagid = a.metertagid
```